# Regular expression and phone number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I want to valdiate the phone number. This is my regexp:

```
[RegularExpression(@"((\+7)|7) ((700|701|702|705|707|712|713|717|718|721|725|726|727|777)) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")]
```

This is test value: 7 (701) 777-7777.

But, it's not working. Where is an error?

Comment: you tell us the error - not the other way around

Comment: So many questions. What country? What error?

Comment: you need to escape the parenthesis if you want to include those in the match. Try something like this: `@"(\+7|7)\s\((700|701|702|705|707|712|713|717|718|721|725|726|727|777)\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}"`

Comment: @IchabodClay: I'm using http://regexhero.net/tester/ for test you regexp, but no match.

Comment: There's some odd formatting going on if you copy/paste it. You need to delete "-\d{4}" and retype it in regexhero. Or just use one of the answers below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the pattern can be simplified into this,

```
(\+)?7\s\(7(0[0125]|1[2378]|2[1567]|77)\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[RegularExpression(@"((\+7)|7) ((700|701|702|705|707|712|713|717|718|721|725|726|727|777)) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")]
                               ^^ There
```

You need to escape the outer parentheses with a backslash.